# Is cosine similarity enough to measure word embedding similarity?

Tags: euclidean, cosine-similarity

Is cosine similarity a good metric to measure word embedding similarity? Suppose that we have two vectors of word embedding in same direction but with different length( first one with len=1 and second with len=10). Almost in articles, the cosine similarity has been calculated, but how we can interpret this above mentioned situation? They are far from each other but in same direction.

Comment: What you mean as len=1? Could you provide a practical example?

Comment: I mean the length of the vector for that embedding is 1. Suppose we have these two vectors: [1,0] , [10,0]